# Is there a way to check an item in a VB.net checked listbox without having to loop through the entire checked list box to find the item?

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I have a checked listbox that is filled with about 100 items although it can be a lot more.  I am pulling in from my database, let's say 3 of items that are in that list.  I only want to check the 3 coming in from the database.

Is there a way to do that without looping through each item in the checked listbox then checking to see if that item is one of the 3 etc.

Comment: MSDN was made for this did you check it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Is there a way to do that without looping through each item`  Yes.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I appreciate the link but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: @MiketheGardener `CheckedItems` gets a list of all checked items all you have to do then is use the `.Contains(MyItem)` to check if it has your value. You could also even use a `FindByValue` trick. Or even using LINQ: `Enumerable.Any` did you try googling your problem?

Comment: Here is what I was looking for:
chklbReports.SetItemChecked(chklbReports.Items.IndexOf(strTEMP, True)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my question:

chklbReports.SetItemChecked(chklbReports.Items.IndexOf(strTEMP, True)

but thank you to whomever down voted my question.  That was awesome of you.

Comment: New member, glad you got it figured out.  I'm usually pretty explicit on why I am downvoting and I'm sorry as it feels like a troll.  At the same time, we have to hear `what efforts were made to resolve the issue` - sometimes in doing this step, you figure out the answer before the negative feedback.

Comment: not a new member.  I have been on here for quite sometime I just don't normally ask for help here as I do figure it out similar to what I did here.  I should have just waited before posting.  I know eventually I will find the solution.  I always do.